# Можно ли узнать, кто из пользователей локальной сети лазил в ту или иную папку с общим доступом?

Tags: windows, администрирование, доступ

Предположим в локальной сети есть общедоступный сервер. На этот сервер админ залил папку с книгами, папку с фильмами, папку с компроматом и папку с порнографией. В первом приближении сервер выглядит как простой компьютер с **windows**, папки помещены в общий доступ стандартными средствами **windows**, при передачи данных используется обычный smb протокол.

**Вопросы:** есть ли возможность узнать (и как?) кто из юзеров в какую папку лазил (что скопировал, что добавил, что удалил и во сколько)? Можно ли используя протокол ftp или другие сетевые протоколы прожурналировать события входа в папки и копирования данных?

Comment: Читать по теме "Файловый аудит".

Comment: дополню . Включение  аудита доступа к объектам добавит больше источникаов данных о попытках доступа к "шарам", появится информация об удаленных клиентах.